# Very newby: how do I properly address applications and links in django?

Tags: django, templates, url

For example:
using the module registration with templates in templates/registration and
an url.py including:

```
url(r'^accounts/', include('registration.backends.default.urls'))
```

what would be the best way to address the registration link: /accounts/register/ without hardcoding it?

but in general, how do I refer an app (and eventually the views) and not use an hard coded URL?

I have seen once a dedicated function but I am not sure.

Comment: Always make the Django docs your first stop. If you haven't already, bookmark it. As @MarkLavin shows, a cursory look over the docs would have made your question irrelevant. Only post a question here when you've fully exhausted all other avenues. This is as much for you as the community, as you'll always learn best from research.

Comment: There are different stages when you read docs. At the first one you might miss something.. Cheers ChrisPratt. What I mean is that learning is not an easy path and I do check the docs, but time to time you forget the obvious ;) Thanks for your comment, apparently it woke up @MarkLavin ;) A+

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside your views and other Python modules you can use the `reverse` function. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/http/urls/#reverse

In the template you would use the `url` template tag. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/templates/builtins/#url

It helps to give your url patterns names to make this reversing as easy as possible. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/http/urls/#id2 The included url patterns in django-registration all have names that you can reference.

Comment: Cheers, I probably was missing the 'names' part.